# Selenium Page Source is Missing Elements

Tags: python, selenium, captcha, recaptcha, hidden

I have a basic Selenium script that makes use of the chromedriver binary. I'm trying to display a page with recaptcha on it and then hang until the answer has been completed and then store that in a variable for future use.

The roadblock I'm hitting is that I am unable to find the recaptcha element.

```
#!/bin/env python2.7
import os
from selenium import webdriver

driverBin=os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/chromedriver")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(driverBin)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get('http://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/')
```

Is there anything special needed to be able to see this element?

Also is there a way to grab the token after user solve without refreshing the page?

As it is now the input type of the recaptcha-token id is hidden. After solve a second recaptcha-token id is created. This is the value I wish to store in a variable. I was thinking of having a loop of checking length of found elements with that id. If greater than 1 parse. But I'm unsure whether the source updates per se.

UPDATE:

With more research it has to do with the nature of the element, particularly: with the tag: `<input type="hidden"`. So I guess to rephrase my question, how does one extract the value of a hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

The element you are looking for (the `input`) is in an iframe. You'll need switch to the iframe before you can locate the element and interact with it.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get('http://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/')

    # Find the iframe and switch to it
    iframe_path = '//iframe[@title="recaptcha widget"]'
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath(iframe_path)
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    # Find the input element
    input_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-token")

    print("Found the input element: ", input_elem)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```